# ç (cedilla) key as Enter

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-layout

In a Spanish keyboard is there a way to use the <kbd>ç</kbd> key as enter while still having <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ç</kbd> as <kbd>}</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> as <kbd>Enter</kbd>? I'm using Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon.

As it says [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49650/how-to-get-keycodes-for-xmodmap) I've used xev to get the key code for kbd>ç and I've assigned it to <kbd>Enter</kbd> like

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 51 = Return"
```

but know I can't write <kbd>}</kbd>.

Comment: https://ictsolved.github.io/remap-key-in-linux/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `xmodmap` and you're almost there with

> ```
> xmodmap -e "keycode 51 = Return"
> ```

but you need to preserve other mappings that were already there for the key. Without your "fix", run `xmodmap -pke` from within your graphical environment. The output should contain something like

```
keycode  51 = ccedilla Ccedilla ccedilla Ccedilla braceright dead_breve braceright
```

Why more than six keysyms? Well, this answer sheds some light: [`xmodmap -pke` shows more than 6 columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299267/108618).

I cannot fully explain the details, still I think you can achieve what you want by replacing `ccedilla` with `Return`, while leaving the rest intact. E.g. In Ubuntu I see this:

```
keycode  51 = backslash bar ccedilla Ccedilla dead_grave dead_breve braceright dead_breve
```

so I replace `ccedilla` with `Return` and run this:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 51 = Return Ccedilla ccedilla Ccedilla braceright dead_breve braceright'
```

but you should adjust *your* line from `xmodmap -pke`.

---

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and I can make the solution permanent by pasting

```
keycode 51 = Return Ccedilla ccedilla Ccedilla braceright dead_breve braceright
```

into my `~/.Xmodmap` file. This works because `/etc/X11/Xsession` sources files from `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/`; one of the files is `80kubuntu-xmodmap` which makes `xmodmap` execute `$HOME/.Xmodmap` (if it exists).

---

If that doesn't work for Linux Mint. You can try the following:

```
cat << EOF > $HOME/.config/autostart/keymapping.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=xmodmap -e 'keycode 51 = Return Ccedilla ccedilla Ccedilla braceright dead_breve braceright'
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
NoDisplay=false
Hidden=false
Name[en_US]=key mapping
Comment[en_US]=No description
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=10
EOF
```

Comment: The non permanent solution worked for me. I'll edit the answer when I find how to make the permanent solution work in Linux Mint Cinnamon.

Comment: @ajr-dev Very well. The answer is now community wiki.